# In place definition of dynamically allocated struct in C

Tags: c, struct

If I were to define a statically allocated struct in place, I'd do:
struct mystructure x = {3, 'a', 0.3};
Is there a way I can do the same in C but using malloc. Ofcourse, I could do a 
struct mystructure x = createNewMystruct(3, 'a', 0.3), (Where I'd define the createNewMyStruct function) but I would like to know if there is some other way possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closest I can think of is this:

```
struct mystructure *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
assert(p);
*p = (const struct mystructure){3, 'a', 0.3};
```

C99 only, so don't come crying to me if it doesn't work in MSVC.

Comment: +1 for advertising compound literals. BTW, I think you should add a `const` to the declaration of the CL, this allows the compiler to allocate it statically, if appropriate.

Comment: @Jens: OK, although I'd be a bit disappointed if the compiler couldn't figure that out for itself even with the non-const literal, under the "as-if" rule.

Comment: @Steve, probably a decent compiler figures that out, you are right. Unfortunately, to my limited experience actual compilers are not so good at it. And the standard says "`compound literals with const-qualified types, need not designate distinct objects`" which in turn implies that if you don't have `const` they must be distinct objects. So by putting in `const` you will always relax the constraints for the compiler as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted.
However, I don't follow the const and compound literal part. Can you please tell me what compound literal is, and why const?
Thanks

Comment: @user247077: a compound literal just means a literal representing a struct or array, as opposed to the numeric and string literals already in C89. As Jens says, `const` might help the compiler avoid actually creating a struct in the program's data area to represent the literal, and instead just emit code to do `p->a = 3; p->b = 'a'; p->c = 3.0;`, if that is more efficient.

Comment: +1 for crying about lack of C99 implementation. I do this on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a temporary variable using the first approach, then `malloc()` another struct and copy the temporary variable over that heap-allocated variable.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you describe can not be done on the heap. (malloc) The closest is calloc() which will initialize all your allocated memory to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to, but you can use the sizeof() function to determine how large any type is, and just malloc what you need. Referencing the correct 'variable' inside of this construct would be your own problem, of course! :-)

```
char* x = malloc(sizeof(int) + sizeof(char) + sizeof(float);
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.  He wants a way to initialise a malloc'd struct.

Comment: Incidentally, your malloc is wrong, apart from not compiling because you missed a close parenthesis, there is a good chance (depending on platform) that you have not allocated enough space due to padding to allow the float to be aligned properly.

Comment: Thanks, I need to sharpen my C skills before I give C advice again. You guys are smok'en! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with an anonymous block:

```
// Anonymous block
{
   struct mystruct tmp = { ... };

   realstruct = malloc ( sizeof ( struct mystruct ) );
   if ( NULL == realstruct )
       goto error;

   *realstruct = tmp;
}
```

...also I think you can do something like this in C99...

```
// After allocation
*realstruct = (struct mystruct){ ... };
```

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to know if there is some other way possible.

Not in standard C, no.